# using spring session with spring 3.1.2 not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-3, spring-session

I want to use spring session mongo with my current spring 3.1.2 project, but failed.
My POM dependency is as this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-data-mongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

And my configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Value("${mongo-url}")
    String mongo_url;

    @Bean
    public JdkMongoSessionConverter jdkMongoSessionConverter() {
            return new JdkMongoSessionConverter(); 
    }


    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        String url = mongo_url;
        ArrayList<ServerAddress> addr = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
        for (String s : url.split(",")) {
            addr.add(new ServerAddress(s));
        }
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo(addr);
        return mongo;
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "mydb");
    }



    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "mydb";
    }
}
```

The problem is after I start this project using:

mvn tomcat7:run,

I got error like this:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: org.springframework.security.saml.web.HttpSessionConfig
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
```

Is spring-session only working with spring4 and above? How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Updated:
I changed the version to 3.2.14.RELEASE:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.14.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.14.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-session-data-mongo</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>    
        </dependency>
```

And the configuration to this one:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    //@Value("${mongo-url}")
    String mongo_url;

    @Bean
    public JdkMongoSessionConverter jdkMongoSessionConverter() {
            return new JdkMongoSessionConverter(); 
    }


    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        mongo_url = "127.0.0.1:27017";// "dev-ngcsc:27017,dev1-ngcsc:27017,dev2-ngcsc:27017";
        String url = mongo_url;
        ArrayList<ServerAddress> addr = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
        for (String s : url.split(",")) {
            addr.add(new ServerAddress(s));
        }
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo(addr);
        return mongo;
    }

    public @Bean MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "ngcsc");
    }



    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "ngcsc";
    }
}
```

And now I got this error:

```
Oct 15, 2016 8:15:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoSessionRepository' defined in class org.springframework.session.data.mongo.config.annotation.web.http.MongoHttpSessionConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations]: : Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/saml/web/HttpSessionConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate org.springframework.security.saml.web.HttpSessionConfig.mongoTemplate() throws java.net.UnknownHostException] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/saml/web/HttpSessionConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate org.springframework.security.saml.web.HttpSessionConfig.mongoTemplate() throws java.net.UnknownHostException] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisStd
```

Seemed mongo issue, any idea that I can improve it?

I have upgraded version to 4, but another issue comes like this:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/http/MongoHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.session.SessionRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Did I miss any bean definition?

Comment: Why use such an ancient version of Spring?

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the documentation

> If you are using other Spring libraries (not required), the minimum
>   required version is Spring 3.2.14. While we re-run all unit tests
>   against Spring 3.2.x, we recommend using the latest Spring 4.x version
>   when possible.

See [spring-session documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#minimum-requirements)

Comment: I have updated the version to 3.2.14, now mongo issue comes, can you help here?

Comment: I am not sure which spring data mongodb version will be used spring-boot-starter-data-mongo. The oldest spring-data-mongo version on the spring page says 4.0.x see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.8.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#requirements

Comment: I have upgraded to 4, and some session dependency is missing as above pasted error, any idea?